# how to use wordpress database to laravel? is there any way?

Tags: database, wordpress, laravel

is there any way to used WordPress database into laravel

my basic need is

I want to use Wordpress database structure into laravel so I can esaly manage my post and category and post meta and all

Thanks you in advance

Comment: If you know how to use database in Laravel you can do that.

Comment: yes you can but you need edit eloquent defaults and relations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the library which is useful for this 
[corcel](https://github.com/corcel/corcel)

or

[Refer link 1](https://laravel-news.com/wordpress-api-with-laravel)

[Refer link 2](https://vegibit.com/how-to-add-a-wordpress-blog-to-your-laravel-application/)

Comment: Thanks, @Pixlogix try to implement this with demo project and its work for the fresh installation hope you don't mind help me if I get any error on my site